# superobject not loaded in hook at codeigniter

Tags: php, hook, codeigniter-3

When I load the hook in codeigniter, hook successfully  load but superobject not.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    // This gives me nothing
    print_r($this->CI);
    // This works fine
    echo "Hello!";

}
```

codeigniter version :3.1.0

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `post_controller_constructor` or `post_controller` , instead of `pre_controller` or `pre_system`.

Check the [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html?highlight=hook).

> No routing or other processes have happened at this point.